# SP Grant Execute

Tags: select, execute, sql-grant, dbo

I have a new role, which should have permission to execute list of SP and  select some Views.
I run grant execute/select to role on `<object>`. Do I need to grant this role select permission to the table used in SP/Views taking in hand that those tables are located in different schemes?

Owner of all schemes/SP/Views across DB is dbo.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why it that "-1", maybe because that person is silly, but anyway the answer is: No.

Explanation:
We don't need to grant select to any object if owner of the object and SP/View is the same.